# Rails is taking the db schema from slave instead of master

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Currently I have the following configuration :

Rails version : rails (3.2.9)
ActiveRecord version : activerecord (3.2.9)
I have a master / slave configured for the MySQL databases.
Master / Slave config is maintained through Octopus gem

Issue :
The structure on Master and Slave is different. Slave has two extra columns which are not there on Master.
During the insert, the insert statement that is being created by rails includes the two extra columns from slave as well and MySQL is failing this insert as these two columns are not present in Master.

Kindly help.

Comment: In your migration file have you added using(:shard_name)? And also add your line of codes for better understanding.

Comment: I am not using the rails migration to alter / create tables. we are doing that directly through MySQL. Any idea where does the ActiveRecord get the schema to form the insert statement. I think the issue lies there only.

Comment: Have you run rake octopus:copy_schema_versions for schema ? If yes, it will generate two different schema in  shard database .

Comment: No, I have not run any rake tasks. The only thing that has been done is 2 new columns have been added to slave db (manually through MySQL alters), which currently are not there in master db.

Comment: Check whether you database has two migration file or not ? If not you can run  rake octopus:copy_schema_versions for schema.